# GET Values from a custom field via JIRA REST API

Tags: rest, jira

I would like to GET all drop down options for a custom field.  For system fields, I use the following URI:

> http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/project/XXXX/components

(for components, versons, etc. Basically system fields), so  I tried the following for a custom field

> http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/project/XXXX/customfield_10000

and got a 404 error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I've been googling for the past 19 hours.  The best I search result I got was the following documentation: [JIRA Developers Documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/jira/6.1.html)

Please assist, I'm not sure What I'm missing

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get that information either from the [createmeta](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/issue-getCreateIssueMeta) or [editmeta](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/issue-getEditIssueMeta) REST resources.

Use editmeta if you want to retrieve the available options when editing a specific issue. E.g.

```
GET /rest/api/2/issue/TEST-123/editmeta
```

Use createmeta when you want to retrieve the options for a project in combination with an issue type. E.g.

```
GET /rest/api/2/issue/createmeta?projectKeys=MYPROJ&issuetypeNames=Bug&expand=projects.issuetypes.fields
```

The customfields with options will be returned like this:

```
"customfield_12345": {
  "schema": {
    "type": "string",
    "custom": "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:select",
    "customId": 12345
  },
  "name": "MySelectList",
  "allowedValues": [
    {
      "self": "http://jira.url/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/14387",
      "value": "Green",
      "id": "14387"
    },
    {
      "self": "http://jira.url/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/14384",
      "value": "Blue",
      "id": "14384"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It returns all custom field except the epic link, do I need to add anything else ?

Comment: What does the epic link have to do with your question?

Comment: The epic link is part of the response. But it's a customfield of class "com.pyxis.greenhopper.jira:gh-epic-link", so not a regular "select" list field with options. It does not have an "allowedValues" element. If you want the possible values for the epic-link field, just search for all Epics. There's no list configured anywhere for that.

Comment: Thanks!! I'm with you

Comment: If you're using the Python Jira API, you can call `jira.editmeta('TEST-123')` after instantiating a JIRA client object.

Comment: Is there a REST API to get the options for just one custom field? I tried 'GET /rest/api/2/customField/{fieldId}/option' with fieldId filled in - got 404.