# JIRA API GET all values for a custom field

Tags: api, get, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to get all possible values for a customfield on JIRA through the GET api.

Example:

I created the "Test API" custom field and gave it three values "API 1", "API 2" and "API 3". The id for this field is 18232.

I'm trying to do this with the following:

https://my-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/18232

I got this from [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/#api-api-2-customFieldOption-id-get)

The headers are one for basic authorization and one with Accept - application/json

No matter what I try to do I keep getting the error

> {"errorMessages":["A custom field option with id '18232' does not exist"],"errors":{}}

Has anyone been sucessful with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GET Values from a custom field via JIRA REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984491/get-values-from-a-custom-field-via-jira-rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the following and I was able to get what I was looking for, hope this helps!

Request:

```
curl -D- -u username:password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://my-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10150
```

Response:

```
{"self":"https://my-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10150","value":"AUG-1999"}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

That rest API call only give you a custom field OPTION value, if you want to list all options of customFileld i think you need a webserviceplugin.